# SQL Where Column Value in Query String

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to build a query that will match with records that have values that are contained in the query string.

For example if I have a `Product` table with `brand` and `name` columns I would want the following query string `Ford engine for car` to match with a record where the brand is set to `Ford` and the name is set to `V8 Engine`.

I originally tried using the `IN` operator but that's not quite what I need. The query needs to be the reverse of a `LIKE` such that if the column value is contained in the query string then the record will match for that query.

Comment: Your requirement is somewhat vague, but it sounds like your goal is to interpret a natural language statement as a search against your database. That won't be very efficient or accurate using SQL You may want to consider a query engine such as http://sphinxsearch.com/

Comment: I don't think what you're looking for exists.  You would need to tokenize your query string and then do a LIKE against both fields for each item.  This will give you some false positives though, so you may want to strip out extraneous words like 'for' if possible.  That being said @EricJ.'s idea seems like a better option.

Comment: Please tag appropriately. MySQL and PostGres are different with different syntax, features and functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmmm . . . I think this does what you want:

```
select p.*
from product p
where $query_string like '%' || brand || '%' and
      $query_string like '%' || name || '%' ;
```

Performance is a different matter.  If that is a concern, perhaps a full text index would help.